# missing icon in my Eclipse Product

Tags: eclipse, plugins, icons

After creating some plugins and fetures, for them-
I created a new product and generated it.
 I provided rebeanding settings and the 7 bmp images for the icon.

All icons are lookoing good (excecutable Icon and window icon ) except the icon in the about entry of help menu... 
Instead my icon a red annoing square is shown...
(by the way, kepler product generation doesn't have this problem, because the "about" entry didn't had an icon at all.. )

what  am i doing wrong?
what can i do about it?

Thank you in advanced!
VADI.

Answer (score 0):

The red square means Eclipse can't find the image.

The most likely problem is that you have not included the image in the `build.properties` file for the plugin. This must list all files and folders that are included in the plugin.

An example build.properties including an image and an icons folder:

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml,\
               css/,\
               icons/,\
               images/,\
               OSGI-INF/,\
               splash.png
source.. = src/
```

Comment: this is not the case because... the rest of the icons are just fine, window icon (left corner icon) and the excecutable icon.. so the resource is defenatelly included...